# php not see variable from another php file

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Im new with php. Start an application using doctrine 2.

I have two files:

bootstrap.php:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode);

$conn = array(
'driver' => 'pdo_pgsql',
'user' => 'postgres',
'password' => '123456', 
'host' => 'localhost', 
'dbname' =>'usrdb',
);

$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

Now i try to call `$entityManager` from another file:

```
<?php
   require_once "bootstrap.php";
   ///***code
   $session = $entityManager->find('Sessions', $_SESSION['id']);
   //**code again
```

And i get error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: entityManager in D:\xampp\htdocs\mapFace-backend\geoserv.auth.login.php on line 23
```

Thsi files located in same directory.
What can be wrong?

**UPDATE**

Full code:

```
<?php
require '\bootstrap.php';
//require_once "geoserv.auth.lastact.php";
function login () {
    //ini_set ("session.use_trans_sid", true);
    //session_start();
    print_r($_SESSION['id']);
    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])){ 
        echo("SESSION");
        if(isset($_COOKIE['login']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])){
            echo("COOKKIE");
            SetCookie("login", "", time() - 1, '/');            
            SetCookie("password","", time() - 1, '/');          

            setcookie ("login", $_COOKIE['login'], time() + 50000, '/');            

            setcookie ("password", $_COOKIE['password'], time() + 50000, '/');          

            $id = $_SESSION['id'];          
            //lastAct($id);             
            return true;
        } else {//иначе добавим cookie с логином и паролем, чтобы после перезапуска браузера сессия не слетала              
            $session = $entityManager->find('Sessions', $_SESSION['id']);               
            if ($session){ //если получена одна строка                              

                setcookie ("login", $session->getUserName(), time()+50000, '/');                
                setcookie ("password", md5($session->getUserName().$session->getPass()), time() + 50000, '/'); 

                $tm = time();
                $session->setLastAct($tm);
                $entityManager->persist($session);
                $entityManager->flush();
                return true;            
            }else{ 
                return false;
            }           
        }   
    }else{
        echo ("NO SESSION");
    }   
}
```

Comment: did u try using `include()` or `require()` only

Comment: @Kaii: yeah i was tried both. But nothing change.

Comment: Did you try to go back to bootstrap.php then check the outputted value of `$entitymanager` ?

Comment: I call `echo $entityManager` in bootstrap.php and get `Object of class Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager could not be converted to string` more interesting that if i call `geoserv.auth.login.php` in console `php geoserv.auth.login.php` i dont get any errors.

Comment: is this the full code?

Comment: Your `require_once` is in a global scope ? Not in a function or method? (scope of `require_once` is explicitly set where you use it.)

Comment: @Kaii: I add full code in question. Please look at it.

Comment: @Koryonik: I put `require` in top of file. Is it mean that bootstrap.php in global_scope?

Comment: Try remove the \ in the filepath : `require "bootstrap.php";`

Comment: `$entityManager` is not in scope in your `login()` function.

Comment: @Koryonik: Yeah `/\` just a typo when i copy a code in question.

Comment: @Phil: I gonna require bootstrap.php inside a function?

Comment: @KliverMax No, pass `$entityManager` in to your `login` function as an argument

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: Ok. `require_once` is in global scope, and you call $entitmanager is in a function (locale scope). Try pass `$entityManager` as function parameter.

Comment: you are trying to call the variable inside a function thats out of its scope mate. try to inject that variable inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
require 'bootstrap.php';  // remove /
//require_once "geoserv.auth.lastact.php";
function login ($entityManager) { // passed the variable here
    //ini_set ("session.use_trans_sid", true);
    //session_start();
    print_r($_SESSION['id']);
    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])){ 
        echo("SESSION");
        if(isset($_COOKIE['login']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])){
            echo("COOKKIE");
            SetCookie("login", "", time() - 1, '/');            
            SetCookie("password","", time() - 1, '/');          

            setcookie ("login", $_COOKIE['login'], time() + 50000, '/');            

            setcookie ("password", $_COOKIE['password'], time() + 50000, '/');          

            $id = $_SESSION['id'];          
            //lastAct($id);             
            return true;
        } else {//иначе добавим cookie с логином и паролем, чтобы после перезапуска браузера сессия не слетала              
            $session = $entityManager->find('Sessions', $_SESSION['id']);               
            if ($session){ //если получена одна строка                              

                setcookie ("login", $session->getUserName(), time()+50000, '/');                
                setcookie ("password", md5($session->getUserName().$session->getPass()), time() + 50000, '/'); 

                $tm = time();
                $session->setLastAct($tm);
                $entityManager->persist($session);
                $entityManager->flush();
                return true;            
            }else{ 
                return false;
            }           
        }   
    }else{
        echo ("NO SESSION");
    }   
}
```